# How to repeat a trial?

Tags: neural-network, hyperparameters, optuna

I would like to know if Optuna offers an option to repeat each trial five times or more to get the average performance of the network over different initial weights.

Answer (score 2):

No. If you want to measure an average of multiple runs, update your objective to repeat your computation inside a trial. A simple example could be the following:

```py
NUM_RUNS = 5


def objective(trial: Trial) -> float:
    num_filters = trial.suggest_int(...)
    hidden_size = trial.suggest_int(...)

    objective_values = []
    for _ in range(NUM_RUNS):
        model = Model(num_filters=num_filters, hidden_size=hidden_size)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        accuracy = model.evaluate(X_valid, y_valid)
        objective_values.append(accuracy)

    return np.mean(accuracy)
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you know if there is a way to parallelize these multiple runs?

Comment: I think we can parallelize by the following steps:

- Create the function (i.e. `evaluate_objective`) that (1) accepts hyperparameters (num_filters and hidden_size in the example) and (2) create/train/evaluate a model and (3) returns a metrics

- Run evaluate_objective in parallel. It might be useful to use joblib or multiprocessing like: `metrics = Parallel(n_jobs=4)(delayed(evaluate_objective)(num_filters, hidden_size) for _ in range(NUM_RUNS))`

- `return np.mean(metrics)`